# When will SharePoint 2013 will officially be available for Organizations to roll-out as Intranet and Public facing?

Tags: 2013, licensing, public-website, cal

We all know SharePoint 2013 is now RTM.

1. Do we know if Volume Licensing customers with Software Assurance
   (SA) will be able to download SharePoint 2013 on-premise through the
   Volume Licensing Service Center? Can they roll-out SP 2013 as Intranet and Public facing?
2. For customers without Software Assurance (SA), will be they also be
   available on the Volume Licensing price list? Can they roll-out SP 2013 as Intranet and Public facing?
3. When will the following language packs will be available? i.e. Danish, Swedish, Norwegian

Answer (score 2):

1 - Do we know if Volume Licensing customers with Software Assurance (SA) will be able to download SharePoint 2013 on-premise through the Volume Licensing Service Center? Can they roll-out SP 2013 as Intranet and Public facing?

> Yes as of Novemeber 1st https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx

2 - For customers without Software Assurance (SA), will be they also be available on the Volume Licensing price list? Can they roll-out SP 2013 as Intranet and Public facing?

> Yes pricing was announced December 1st for non SA peeps. You will need to login to view this information

3 - When will the following language packs will be available? i.e. Danish, Swedish, Norwegian

> According to the [Language pack for 2013 preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30347) all of the 2010 languages listed in [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff463597%28v=office.14%29.aspx) are available

Comment: Danish, Swedish, Norwegian language packs are still not available as of now. Your information is incorrect.

Comment: Are you looking at the SharePoint foundation pack?

Comment: I am looking for both foundation and RTM

Comment: Is there someone answering my question?

Answer (score 0):

The RTM bits have been available to everyone, including Volume Licensees [since the end of October](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-makes-office-2013-available-to-volume-licensees-7000006711/) so I don't think there is anything preventing companies from going live right now.

Comment: Unless am I wrong, the mandatory server licenses and CAL can't be - yet - purchased. You can deploy on trial mode though but I didn't saw a trial key for RTM edition (unlike preview)

Comment: Unfotunately, that doesn't answer my question still!

Comment: @FrancoisVerbeeck could you please post the detail reply as well

Comment: "Unfotunately, that doesn't answer my question still" that's why I added it as a comment to someone else reply. I just wanted to help, I don't have enough information to give a worthy reply. Sorry.